# SparkSQL error Table Not Found

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, cassandra

**I converted an RDD[myClass] to dataframe and then register it as an
   SQL table**

```
my_rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("my_rdd")
```

**This table is callable and can be demonstrated with following command**

```
%sql

SELECT * from my_rdd limit 5
```

**But the next step gives error, saying Table Not Found: my_rdd**

```
val my_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from my_rdd limit 5")
```

**Quite newbie for Spark. Do not understand why this is happening. Can anyone help me out of this?**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Table Not Found: my_rdd
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleCatalog$$anonfun$1.apply(Catalog.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleCatalog$$anonfun$1.apply(Catalog.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.SimpleCatalog.lookupRelation(Catalog.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$6.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$6.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:207)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildrenDown(TreeNode.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:207)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildrenDown(TreeNode.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.analyzed(SQLContext.scala:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(SQLContext.scala:1069)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:915)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:68)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:73)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:75)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:77)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:79)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:81)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:83)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:85)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:87)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:89)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:91)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:93)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:95)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:97)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:99)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:101)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:103)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:105)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:107)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:109)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:111)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:113)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:115)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:117)
    at <init>(<console>:119)
    at .<init>(<console>:123)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpretInput(SparkInterpreter.java:556)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:532)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.interpret(SparkInterpreter.java:525)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.ClassloaderInterpreter.interpret(ClassloaderInterpreter.java:57)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:264)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:118)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Try using the below link for reference it might help you solve the issue: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: Could you post a minimal complete example? Right now it's not entiretly clear what you are attempting http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Make sure the sqlContext you register your DataFrame and the sqlContext you execute your SQL are the **SAME** sqlContext object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure to import the implicits._ from the same SQLContext. Temporary tables are kept in-memory in one specific SQLContext.

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
my_rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("my_rdd")

val my_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from my_rdd LIMIT 5")
my_df.collect().foreach(println)
```

Comment: I had `import sqlContext._`, adding implicits fixed my issue.

Comment: @DanCiborowski-MSFT
after importing implicts still i am unable to use the table.
I am creating the temp table inside map method of dstream.

val conbinedSensorStreams = sensor1StreamDF.union(sensor2StreamDF).foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("sensor_StreamTableTmp"))
sqlContext.sql("Insert into table vsc.hive_snsrtable select * from sensor_StreamTableTmp");

Please let me know if this can be done

Comment: @VikramSinghChandel Not sure about the 'insert' clause but for selecting from a temptable defined inside the forEachRDD method, the import sqlContext.implicits._ works as mentioned by Marius

Answer (score 1):

I found it easy to cause problems with temptables if there is more than one open zeppelin session, either in your own browser, or from someone else using the same server.  The variable sqlContext is shared across those sessions and its easy to overwrite the value of it.

Answer (score 1):

So as the solution of this problem I copied **core-site.xml**,**hive-site.xml** and **hdfs-site.xml** files into **conf** directoy.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same error but in different case ,by solve it with using the same context. If you use `hiveContext`, make sure that you use it all the time, for example first `sqlContext.sql("load data input XXX")` , and then if you use `hiveContext.sql("select * from XXX")`, you will meet this problem.

Every context has it`s lifecycle. So do not use two context with the same dataFrame .

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with a similar problem. I was loading a table which was not present in the warehouse folder whereas Hive console was showing me the table name. You can check the detailed description of the table you are loading using ***describe formatted table_name***.  You don't need to copy any file to spark/conf folder. It is already integrated.