# Zeppelin - Dynamic Drop Down Based on SQL Query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Below is the code to execute a spark sql statement

```
%sql
select name,
age,
year,
country
sum(salary) as annual_income
from data 
where country="${Country=USA,USA|Europe|India|China}"
group by name,age,year,country.
```

In the above statement, the drop box is populated by static values given. Is it possible to populate the dropbox dynamically using a SQL Statement in **Zeppelin**.

Comment: have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279889/dynamic-interactive-dashboard-with-zeppelin-notebook/39286425#39286425

Comment: Thanks,Will look into it.