# Zeppling twitter streaming example, unable to

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

When following the zeppelin tutorial for streaming tweets and querying them using SparkSQL, am running into error where the 'tweets' temp table is not found. The exact code being used and links referred as as follows

Ref: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/quickstart/tutorial.html

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import scala.io.Source
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import java.io.File
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import sys.process.stringSeqToProcess

/** Configures the Oauth Credentials for accessing Twitter */
def configureTwitterCredentials(apiKey: String, apiSecret: String, accessToken: String, accessTokenSecret: String) {
  val configs = new HashMap[String, String] ++= Seq(
    "apiKey" -> apiKey, "apiSecret" -> apiSecret, "accessToken" -> accessToken, "accessTokenSecret" -> accessTokenSecret)
  println("Configuring Twitter OAuth")
  configs.foreach{ case(key, value) =>
    if (value.trim.isEmpty) {
      throw new Exception("Error setting authentication - value for " + key + " not set")
    }
    val fullKey = "twitter4j.oauth." + key.replace("api", "consumer")
    System.setProperty(fullKey, value.trim)
    println("\tProperty " + fullKey + " set as [" + value.trim + "]")
  }
  println()
}

// Configure Twitter credentials
val apiKey = "xxx"
val apiSecret = "xxx"
val accessToken = "xx-xxx"
val accessTokenSecret = "xxx"

configureTwitterCredentials(apiKey, apiSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._


@transient val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
@transient val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
@transient val twt = tweets.window(Seconds(60), Seconds(2))

val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
case class Tweet(createdAt:Long, text:String)
twt.map(status=>
        Tweet(status.getCreatedAt().getTime()/1000, status.getText())).foreachRDD(rdd=>
        // Below line works only in spark 1.3.0.
        // For spark 1.1.x and spark 1.2.x,
        // use rdd.registerTempTable("tweets") instead.
        rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("tweets")
)

ssc.start()
```

In the next paragraph, i have the SQL select statement

```
%sql select createdAt, count(1) from tweets group by createdAt order by createdAt
```

Which throws the following exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table not found: tweets;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.getTable(Analyzer.scala:305)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get the above example running by making following edits. Am not sure, if this change was needed due to version upgrade of Spark (v1.6.3) or some other underlying architecture nuances i might be missing, but eitherways

REF: [SparkSQL error Table Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263646/sparksql-error-table-not-found)

In the second para' instead of directly invoking as SQL syntax, try using the sqlContext as follows

```
val my_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from sweets LIMIT 5")
my_df.collect().foreach(println)
```