# 44: error: value read is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am using Spark 1.6.1, and Scala 2.10.5. I am trying to read the csv file through com.databricks.
While launching the spark-shell, I use below lines as well

spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 --driver-class-path path to/sqljdbc4.jar, and below is the whole code

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext


val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._

val df = SQLContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferScheme","true").option("header","true").load("path_to/data.csv");
```

I am getting below error:-

error: value read is not a member of object org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, 
and the "^" is pointing toward "SQLContext.read().format" in the error message.

I did try the suggestions available in stackoverflow, as well as other sites as well. but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLContext` means object access - static methods in class.

You should use `sqlContext` variable, as methods are not static, but are in class

So code should be:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferScheme","true").option("header","true").load("path_to/data.csv");
```

Comment: But now I get another error

conf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@b43db07
sc: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@774cc4a9
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@62d42eb7
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

What should I make out of this?

Comment: @user3521180 It's related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263646/sparksql-error-table-not-found. It's unrelated to this question and solving will require more info - full code and exception stacktrace - so I suggest posting new question